# iframe in background with z-index, no menu controls?

Tags: html, css, iframe, z-index

I am developing a webpage which puts an iframe as a background due to other div elements "playing with it". Using z-index, it is in the background area, visible, but i need to be able to control it, and the controls that are usually present are missing. Here's the main code:

Here's the html:

```
<div class="bg-about">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/54960454?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0;autoplay=1"></iframe>
  <div id="iframe"></div>
</div>
```

Here's the css:

```
iframe {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#iframe {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Any ideas? I really need the controls. 
Note: the background is not actually behind anything, but due to formatting, it must be in a background. And I'm not sure why its displayed wrong.

Comment: Do you have a link to a webpage that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: No unfortunately, the website is still in development. I can only provide the source code.

Comment: That is okay. Can you edit your post and place the source code in a code snippet?

Comment: What is the content inside the `#iframe` element ?

Comment: That's a lot of code... here's a link to paste bin. http://pastebin.com/qFpd5366 http://pastebin.com/s5eX3iF4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are covering the video with the #iframe, so you can't rollover video to view controls. I just swapped the z index of video to 2 and #iframe to 1. You were just covering video with div by mistake.

```
iframe {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 }
 #iframe {
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     overflow: auto;
}
```

here is link: https://jsfiddle.net/keinchy/asga90Lg/

Comment: Sweet! That was it! Thank you!

Comment: glad i could help. you mind marking this as answered.